# Can we have country tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Questions like [these](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14619/why-is-butter-usually-labeled-sweet-cream) could do with a country tag (see the comment answer).

I tried to edit one in, only to find out that there seem to be no country tags....

Answer (score 3):

I'd be more inclined to just mention it in the question when it's relevant. Tagging is more a searching/organization thing than a way to convey important information about the question. You don't see the tags until you're done reading the question, and even then a lot of people skim over them, so tagging something [united-states](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) will only help so much.

Imagine you wrote a question "How do I make my pie less juicy?" (plus a suitable body) and never said what kind of pie it was until adding a [blueberries](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blueberries) at the end. Seems kind of unclear, right? I think the same applies here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine a country tag would be useful for very many questions.  Your example might be one - terminology that's specific to one country - but even for that one, I don't think it would make sense to hang a "US" tag on it: there's lot's of cross-border shopping between the US and Canada, so sweet cream butter shows up here as well, but then does that mean it needs two country tags?